# Meaning of the phrase "strike a bonanza"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms, sentence

> Just as a tribe might occasionally **strike a bonanza** in the game of primitive warfare, sometimes a state might do the same, given the opportunities offered an Alexander the Great or a Hernan Cortes.

What is the meaning of the phrase "strike a bonanza"? "Achieve great success"?

Comment: Which bit are you having a problem with?

Comment: What is the meaning of the phrase "strike a bonanza"? "Achieve great success"?

Comment: [Strike](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike) (transitive verb) "18 a : to come to : ATTAIN" or "b : to come upon : DISCOVER".

Comment: Yes, 'achieve great success'; 'hit lucky'. I don't think it's a great choice of metaphor here. And 'given the opportunities that Alexander the Great or Hernan Cortes had' would be my choice..

Comment: Many-many thanks for your kind help and explanations!

Comment: The figurative use is from the domain of mining, where to "strike a bonanza" means to hit (with digging tools) a very rich deposit of valuable ore, the sudden increase in wealth  translating to great success.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable clarification!

Comment: Does this mean only material success (getting rich) or victory in a broader sensed?

Comment: The sentence says it's referring to war: so **win a war quickly and powerfully**.

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your answer!

Comment: @Dmitry In your questions, please include exactly what part of the sentence you don't understand. Not doing so leads to unnecessary conversations and answers in the comments area. I'll [edit] your comments into the body of your question this time, but please do so yourself in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "strike a bonanza" isn't an idiomatic expression, but the individual words "strike" and "bonanza".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike):

> **strike** *transitive verb*
> **18 a :** to come to : attain
> **b :** to come upon : discover
> *strike gold*

Also from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bonanza):

> **bonanza** *noun*
> **2 a :** something that is very valuable, profitable, or rewarding
> *a box-office bonanza*

So in your context, "strike a bonanza" means to attain something that is very valuable, in this case, it probably means a victory that gives access to valuable resources.

Comment: Thank you very much! If so, the phrase "strike a bonanza" in this context does mean material success (getting rich), not just a military victory?

Comment: May I reformulated this sentence in such a way: "Just as a tribe could hit a big jackpot in a primitive war, so a state could suddenly become rich if, by chance, its own Alexander the Great or Hernan Cortes appeared"?

Comment: Let me provide a broader context for this sentence.

Comment: In early states and empires warfare still served the function of solidarity, but now to avenge offenses against a theocratic monarch rather than against the community; and its priorities shifted, for the major functions of war were now economic ("gain") and political ("safety") rather than social ("glory"). The political balance of power has not followed any clear line of evolution either. Just as a tribe might occasionally strike a bonanza in the game of primitive warfare, sometimes a state might do the same, given the opportunities offered an Alexander the Great or a Hernan Cortes.

Comment: My first interpretation of this sentence (before your answer) was this:

Comment: "Just as a tribe could sometimes achieve great success in primitive warfare, so a state could sometimes do the same if it had such opportunities as Alexander the Great or Hernan Cortes". How do you think is it correct?

Comment: A "bonanza" is the sudden acquisition of something of enormous value. In this context, it almost certainly means military victory, and *likely* means material success. Or, it may be that merely controlling that land or those people has some huge advantage. The rest of your questions here are outside the context of your original question.